# Hoe does one move the axis.ticks.x.bottom nearer to my graphic?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, xticks

Unfortunately I‘m only able to move the label nearer to my axis by using element_text(hjust = 1). But I want to move my ticks nearer to the ordinate.

I did not find any function which solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.